# Object prototype is not working as expected, properties are stuck in __propto__

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an issue with the following code in Chrome Version 43.0.2357.132

```
var MyObject = function () {
    this.prop0 = 'test0';
};
MyObject.prototype = {
    prop1 : 'test1',
    prop2 : 'test2'
}
var myObject = new MyObject();        
console.log(myObject, MyObject.prototype);
```

I was expecting to see `'test1'` and `'test2'` properties included in `object`. Recently this doesn't work as expected in Chrome and in Firefox. Internet Epxlorer seems to work just fine. I can't understand at all why this happens.

Try this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrian_moisa/wjszw185/3/) with the console opened.

**Chrome console:**

[image]

**Internet explorer console:**

[image]

Comment: Don't name it `Object`, this is just an issue with the console, it will work fine.

Comment: No difference at all named as `MyObject` or anyhting else.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Any problem?

Comment: Is it correct. Under `__proto__` you will see what is being defined to its prototype, but you still can access it using `object.test1`.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa, take a look  http://jsfiddle.net/9pz09ndk/

Comment: You are right, I was so convinced that I will see {prop0, prop1, prop2}. My fault.